# Get User in a Doctrine EventListener

Tags: symfony

when I register a new Plasmid Entity, I want give him an automatic name (like: p0001, p0002, p0003), to do this, I need to select in the database the last Plasmid entity for a specific User, get its autoName, and use this previous name to define the new one.

But, when I inject the token_storage in my listener, the token is null... In the controller, I can have the user, it's work.

The service.yml

```
    app.event_listener.plasmid:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\PlasmidListener
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

And, the PlasmidListener

```
class PlasmidListener
{
private $user;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    // If the entity is not a Plasmid, return
    if (!$entity instanceof Plasmid) {
        return;
    }

    // Else, we have a Plasmid, get the entity manager
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    // Get the last plasmid Name
    $lastPlasmid = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Plasmid')->findLastPlasmid($this->user);

    // Do something with the last plasmid in the database
}
}
```

If someone know why I can get the actual user in the Doctrine Listener ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you should store pointer to tokenStorage class in your service instead of user object:

```
class PlasmidListener
 {
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but do you have an idea why the TokenStorage is empty in the constructor and contain something in the prePersist function ?

Comment: Service is initialized at start and user can be not authenticated yet. Even user and token can change during request, but no service, is like static class with static properties. That's my idea :)

Comment: @malcolm any idea where to find documentation on this?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid error in Symfony4 and above, use **TokenStorageInterface** instead of TokenStorage

For example

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
```

And in your constructor :

```
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

To get the user and its details in **prePersist** :

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```