# Symfony2 get logged in user in doctrine event listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, event-listener, circular-reference

I have created an event listener class for postPersist, PostUpdate and postRemove methods of doctrine.

I need logged in user id in my class, i have tried injecting `@security.context` , `@security.token_storage` and `@session`
I got circular reference error even i have tried injecting `@service_container` and use `container->get()` i got same circular reference error.

> ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for     > service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"

my code in serviec.yml code is like

```
    my.listener:
     class: \projectCreateEventListener
     arguments: ["@service_container"]
     tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate }
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postRemove }
```

my event listener class is like

```
    class myListener
    {
       private $container;

       public function 
       __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
       {
        $this->container = $container;
       }

       public function prePersist(LifeCycleEventArgs $args)
       {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        //Circular reference error
        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')-
        >getToken()->getUser();

        //getToken() is always null

        //Circular reference error
        $user = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')-
        >getToken()->getUser();

        //getToken() is always null

        //Circular reference error
        $userId = $this->container->get('auth.user')-
        >getIdentity()['id'];
       }
    }
```

Although i am getting logged in user information in my code before `$this->persist()` in `$this->container->get('auth.user')->getIdentity()['id'];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get User in a Doctrine EventListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087840/get-user-in-a-doctrine-eventlistener)

Comment: So what version of Symfony are you using because security.context went away a long time ago.  I suspect you have other stuff going on.  Tying a doctrine listener directly to Symfony is probable the best approach.  Consider using the Symfony event dispatcher for this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one. When creating the doctrine service the listener is attached while constructing. If the listener you are trying to build uses another service (or some other service down the line) that requires doctrine in any way you get the circular reference.

But you can build around it.

1. Inject the eventDispatcher into your Listener
2. Create a custom event (or multiple) http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#creating-and-dispatching-an-event
3. Dispatch the event in the prePersist, postPersists methods.
4. Build another listener that subscribes to your custom event and handle your logic there.

What this achieves is: Your custom event listener will only be initialized when your custom event is actually fired. At that point the crucial services like doctrine are already up and running and you avoid the circular reference problem.

Had a similar issue in my project and solved it this way. Not really sure if it's the most elegant way but it definitely works. (If someone has a better solution i'd welcome it too).

Comment: did you see my comment reg. duplicate? check it out

Comment: i saw it but the question suggests his problem isn't that he doesn't know how to inject the necessary classes into the listener but rather when he does it creates an circular reference error, which breaks the framework completely. (Not sure why though but to figure that out you would need to look at the complete DI hierarchy of the project)