# getUser Entity in EventSubscriber

Tags: symfony

I began to build my first web application with symfony. In this app I got user management with authentification and multilanguage. In the user database tabel is a lang column for each user. I got the changing of the default language for the app by changing it through a _GET parameter and also by the login by the database value running.
Now I want to change the value in the database automatically by switching the language through the URL _GET parameter in the EventSubscriber.
Unfortunately I got no idea how to get the user entity in my 'onKernelRequest' function to save the selecte language in the database.
All the logic of changing the language is done in the following code:

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;
    private $allowedLangs;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, $defaultLocale = 'de')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
        $this->allowedLangs = ['de', 'en'];
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } elseif(array_key_exists('_locale', $_GET) && array_search($_GET['_locale'], $this->allowedLangs) !== FALSE) {
            $request->setLocale($_GET['_locale']);
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $_GET['_locale']);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => array(array('onInteractiveLogin', 15)),
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 20)),
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: hi, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870272/how-to-get-the-current-logged-user-in-a-service

Answer (score 5):

First I would split `LocaleSubscriber`  class and move `onKernelRequest` and `onInteractiveLogin` to separate listeners / subscribers - less dependencies for each services.

To get current user in `onKernelRequest` event you need to inject `TokenStorage` service:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $em;

    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, 
        EntityManagerInterface $em
    ) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return ;
        }

        if (!$token->isAuthenticated()) {
            return ;
        }

        if (!$user = $token->getUser()) {
            return ;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // update user
        $user->setLocale($locale);

        $this->em->flush($user);

    }

}
```

Note this is not tested.

Comment: you'll have to check `!is_object($user = $token->getUser()` too because e.g. for anonymous users `getUser()` will return a string only

Comment: `$token->isAuthenticated()` is tested before, so it's ok

Comment: I set up a new EventSubscriber next to my old one. I tried to use the class TokenStorage in the constructor with an error message in the frontend: `Cannot autowire service "App\EventSubscriber\UserLocaleSubscriber": argument "$tokenStorage" of method "__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface" instead.` I also tried TokenStorageInterface but this is always empty.

Comment: Do I have to do something different in the authentication process to get data out of the TokenStorageInterface?

Comment: if empty please check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087840/get-user-in-a-doctrine-eventlistener

Comment: Updated for `TokenStorageInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for the empty token is the wrong event. I switched to "KernelEvents::CONTROLLER". Now I got my User Entity.
My working code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $em;
    private $allowedLangs;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->allowedLangs = ['de', 'en'];
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        if(array_key_exists('_locale', $_GET) && array_search($_GET['_locale'], $this->allowedLangs) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!$token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
                return ;
            }

            if (!$token->isAuthenticated()) {
                return ;
            }

            if (!$user = $token->getUser()) {
                return ;
            }

            $locale = $_GET['_locale'];
            // update user
            $user->setLocale($locale);

            $this->em->flush($user);
            $request->setLocale($locale);
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(array('onKernelController', 1)),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpfull but I use the Security component instead of TokenStorageInterface

Answer (score 0):

Entity is present in LifecycleEventArgs.

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
```